# parallel processing with loop construct in java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am working to create a crawler- a java web app, in which users can define crawl jobs, which extract and store information from specific websites.

As part of this work, there is a 'loop' construct... it has a list portion, which is evaluated initially (and typically represents a list of values)... After that is the loop body, which is executed once for each item in the list (from the list portion mentioned previously).

Note that there can be a loop construct within another loop construct, and so on.

The problem is, sometimes one list can contain millions of rows of data - and the body is to be executed for each row in this list. The body has a start index value, upper bound for the index, and is incremented by one.

What I want to do is, for a single level loop, initially calculate the list value and store it in database. After that, instead of executing the body in one go, split it up into different sections so that different sections of the list are processed in parallel.

However, how do I split up a job for an n-level loop? (Ie one loop within one loop and so on.)

Is there some recommended way of doing such processing... Any tutorial or guide you could point me to, would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest packing the processing logic for 1 element of the list into a Runnable or Callable, and then pass them to an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) for execution. This will run tasks in parallel in different worker-threads. Of course it depends on how many cores your machine has, how "parallel" this will really be.
If each element of the list can be processed completely independent of all the others, than this would be the way to go for me, instead of messing around myself with Threads and dividing the list into sublists etc.

Answer (score 0):

According your description, i got that you are fetching the source code of xyz website and scrap data from that.

You can use XPath and RegularExpression to do this kind of task as its best. use `JSOUP` for that ,it helps you a lot.

As far as parallelization is concern you can use the `.select` , `getElementbyId`, `getElementByClass` of `JSOUP` (it's a opensource). than simply put a

```
for(i=0 ;i< length;i++)
{   

    i am fetching i;
    i am fetching i+1;
    int temp=i+1;
    if(temp>=length)
    {  
        break;
    }
}
```

hope this helps: http://jsoup.org

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great candidate for the [Java 7 fork / join framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you create 3 thread: T1, T2, T3. and following is the looping construct, for eaxmple

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<100; k++)
        {
            // do some processing.
        }
    }
}
```

Modify the increment part as `i += no. of threads`. In this case it will be `i += 3`

Thus, the initial values of i, j, k will vary for each thread.

For T1: `i = 0;`

For T2: `i = 1;`

For T3: `i = 2;`

Similary the loop limit can be set.